# Change row colour based on criteria of 3x cells EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to format the rows to be either red, yellow or blue based on whether one or more cells have been ticked.

So if column E has `Y` in that row (eg. E3) then the whole row would be blue, if F has `Y` then it would be yellow and if G has `Y` then it would be red.

I would normally use:

```
=IF(G="Y",TRUE,IF(F="Y",TRUE,IF(E="Y",TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

But how would I specify which `TRUE` is which colour?

Comment: Create 3 rules, one for each color.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use VBA. Click "Visual Basic" from the "Developer" tab. Then click "Insert" above and add a module. If you then paste the code below and press F5, you will get the result you want as in the photo below. I assumed there were 11 lines in my code. You can change the number 11 by yourself.

```
> Sub colour()
>     For i = 1 To 11
>         If Cells(i, "E").Value = "Y" Then
>             Cells(i, "E").EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbBlue
>         End If
>         If Cells(i, "F").Value = "Y" Then
>             Cells(i, "F").EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
>         End If
>         If Cells(i, "G").Value = "Y" Then
>             Cells(i, "G").EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
>         End If
>     Next 
> End Sub
```

[image: Goal]